# local state values cant be equal to redux state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

hi I am using redux in the react and I have a form and the form data (specially the value of the form elements when user types something) is stored inside the local state of my react component. and at the same time I have a dispatch incrementing a counter by one and I call it when onchanged function is called on the form elements. and I show the counter data taken from redux state. so the data stored in redux is the number of keys pressed. 
the issue is the value of counter cannot be entered into the form inputs. for example if i press any key (for example type a letter ) my redux counter value would be 1 and now I cant type number 1 in the inputs. the local state does not change. 
here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Box} from "@material-ui/core";
import {FormElements} from "../forms/formElements";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";

class Login extends React.Component {
state = {
        counter: 0,

    comps: {
        Lusername: {
            required: true,
            label: "username",
            id: "Lusername",
            type: "string",
            value: ""
        },
        Lpassword: {
            required: true,
            type: "password",
            id: "Lpassword",
            label: "password",
            value: ""
        }

    }
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onInc();                 //redux dispatch
    let {id, value} = event.target     //local state
    let comps = this.state.comps
    comps[id].value = value
    this.setState({comps: comps})
}

render() {
    return (
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.props.onclickAway}>
            <Box m={2}>
                <p>{this.props.ctr}</p>
                <FormElements comps={this.state.comps} handleChange={this.handleChange}
                              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></FormElements>
                <Box mt={2}>
                    <NavLink to={"/signup"} style={{textDecoration: "none", color: "#0e404c"}}>
                        <Typography component={"h5"}>don't have an account? signUp</Typography>
                    </NavLink>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </ClickAwayListener>
    );
};
};
const MapStateToProps = state => {
    return {ctr: state.counter}

}

const MapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onInc: () => dispatch({type: "INC"})
    }
}
export default connect(MapStateToProps, MapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems here. First, you have a local state also called `counter`. it looks you are confused about redux state. React's local state is not the same as Redux's state, is a total different state. you better remove `counter` from your local state, there is no point if you use redux for counter state imo.

Second, these lines:

```
let comps = this.state.comps
comps[id].value = value
this.setState({comps: comps})
```

`comps` is an object, reference based, which means at 2nd line you are mutating state directly, which is bad practice and can lead to weird behaviors. keep in mind, `comps` has also nested object so a shallow destructuring like `const comps = { ...this.state.comps }` wont be enough. you either need to use a deepClone function from a helper lib or you do something like below to create a whole new object:

```
const oldComps = this.state.comps
const Lusername = { ...oldComps.Lusername }
const Lpassword = { ...oldComps.Lpassword }
const comps = { Lusername, Lpassword }
comps[id].value = value
```

That way you are not mutating state directly, and can manipulate it safety.

**update**

edit as the following:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  event.persist()
  // ...comps logic
  this.setState({comps: comps}, this.props.onInc)
}
```

event is react's synthetic event. It can be nullified for reuse as [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) say. it seems that's the case here.

the second change is for consistency. Increment should be triggered after comps state is updated imho. You can pass your onInc function as second argument, which will be triggered after state is updated.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes my code originally was right  as you said. but i changed it to find the problem and i forgot to correct it again.  but the problem is the <p> element in the login form that shows the redux state ctr when i hide it everything is fine

Comment: I edited my post. I think it's related to event being nullified. if it still fails, the error is elsewhere, and you may need to share the reducer and FormElements files.

at your side, for further investigation, you can use `debugger` or `console.log` at Login's update state lifecycle to track the changes, thoug it's better and easier with redux and react extensions to realize what's going wrong.